# Are there any beginner-friendly courses teaching how to create a programming language?

Tags: programming-languages

There are many excellent step-by-step courses (free and paid) teaching you how a specific programming language works and how to use it to create applications. I've benefited a lot from these courses.

Now, I'm looking to go a layer deep and learn how to create a programming language from scratch (such as javascript or python). However, I haven't found a single "step-by-step" course (that's beginner-friendly and that contains practice exercises) that teaches how to create such languages.

In short, I'm looking for a course that teaches how to create a programming language, with the **same quality** as the courses that teach you how to create applications using the most popular languages today.

Does such a course exist in the first place and if so, could you show me where? And if not, what other quality resources are available?

(apart from the odd article on the internet with just an overview of the process of creating a language or a youtube video that doesn't explain anything step-by-step being far from being beginner-friendly or instructive)

Comment: https://craftinginterpreters.com/ might be something like what you're looking for.

Comment: That's great! Thanks